# How to test streaming window aggregations?

Tags: apache-spark, scalatest, spark-structured-streaming

I read some data off Kafka and perform window aggregations over it in the following manner:

```scala
inputDataSet
      .groupBy(functions.window(inputDataSet.col("timestamp"), "1 minutes"),
        col("id")))
      .agg(count("secondId").as("myCount"))
```

How do I unit test this piece of code? All examples over the net are around Dstreams, but I am using a data set by loading from Kafka in this manner:

```scala
sparkSession.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Settings.KAFKA_URL)
      .option("subscribe", Settings.KAFKA_TOPIC1)
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest").load()
      .select(from_json(col("value").cast("String"), mySchema).as("value"))
```

and passing this dataset to my aggregation function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard of a testing framework that would help you with the testing of a streaming Datasets out of the box (beside the test suite in Spark itself that it uses internally).

If I were to test a streaming Dataset I'd **not** use the Kafka source since it does not add much to the testing yet introduces another layer where things may get wrong.

I'd use `memory` [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/memory.scala#L40-L46) and [sink](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/memory.scala#L182). I'd also review the tests for Structured Streaming in the Spark repo, esp. [StreamingAggregationSuite](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingAggregationSuite.scala#L46) since you asked about windowed streaming aggregates. Use the tests as a set of guidelines that you could employ for your own tests.